# Time stored in the DB is 2 hours before the picked one

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a project in Symfony 2.7.

We got the following issue :

In somes places, the user have to pick a date and a time for event or reminder etc.
They can choose it with the foundation datetimepicker.

The data send by the request seems good :
[title => Vermifuge, date => 05.10.2016 16:00, pet => 22, description => , renewable => 1, delay => 3 months, nextDate => 05.01.2017 16:00, active => 1, _token => QTvz3ykjcngQh2Y5SvW5KWdO2D35Ue8m8CfFtZBQxDc] (c/c from the symfony toolbar)

But when in the controller i dump the values :

```
    $this->setup($request);
    $entity = $this->findOrThrowNotFound($id);

    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('edit', $entity->getPet(), 'Unauthorized access!');

    $editForm = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);
    dump($editForm['date']);
    dump($editForm['date']->getData());
```

First dump is :

```
Form {#2369 ▼
-config: FormBuilder {#2370 ▶}
-parent: Form {#2363 ▶}
-children: OrderedHashMap {#2371 ▶}
-errors: []
-submitted: true
-clickedButton: null
-modelData: DateTime {#2336 ▶}
-normData: DateTime {#2336 ▶}
-viewData: "05.10.2016 16:00"
-extraData: []
-transformationFailure: null
-defaultDataSet: true
-lockSetData: false
}
```

And the second one :

```
DateTime {#4733 ▼
+"date": "2016-10-05 14:00:00.000000"
+"timezone_type": 1
+"timezone": "+00:00"
}
```

So at one moment the time change.

In my phpinfo() i have :

date/time support   enabled

"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2016.3

Timezone Database   internal

Default timezone    Europe/Zurich

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the time of your DB isn't the same as the servers, try this query in your db:

```
SELECT now();
```

And then try to dump it from php:

```
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');    // MySQL datetime format
echo $now->getTimestamp();
```

Hope it'll help you...

Comment: Hi,
First, thanks for your help.
My first thought was also that there was something wrong in the database, but the SELECT now() return '2016-10-05 09:52:00' and the php code return '2016-10-05 09:52:25' and '1475653945' so apparently they are configure the same (and right)

Comment: It must be something with timezones, Zurich -> UTC+01:00.
Beside your php.ini, you could set this in symfony as default timezone (google it).
Maybe you have hidden TimezoneType field somwhere? [http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/timezone.html]

Comment: In the php.ini i don't have any timezone set, but when i make a dump(date_default_timezone_get()); i get the correct "Europe/Zurich".
I agree with you that somewhere in the code there is a TimeZone who is set but can't find out :(
I wil continue digging